# JQuery + RequestContextUtils + ApplicationContext

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

JQuery not able to load jsp page when it contains jsp code having reference to RequestContextUtils.

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext,org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils,org.sunshine.location.LocationService,org.sunshine.domain.Location,java.util.List"%>
<%
   out.println("request:" + request.getContextPath());
   ApplicationContext locationContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);
   LocationService locationService = (LocationService) locationContext.getBean("locationService");
   List<Location> locations = locationService.getLocations();
   out.println(locations);
%>
   <table id="location-table" width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0"
        cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <c:forEach items="<%=locations%>" var="location">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${location.id}" /></td>
                <td><a href="index.htm?store=${location.id}"><c:out
                            value="${location.name}" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

The above jsp page works fine if I access it normally. But when I use JQuery's load / get method as below - it fails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("jsp/locations.jsp",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("locad");
  $("#locations-column").load("jsp/locations.jsp");
});
```

I commented all the unnecessary code to find out the root cause. I found ApplicationContext locationContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request); statement makes jquery to not to load the page.

Exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet

Wondering why? how it web context is found when it is run as normal jsp file and why not when it is load via JQuery.

Can someone help me in know why this is happening? how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance
-Vijay Daniel

Comment: This error means that the request does not pass throught Spring's front controller/filter. Can you check this? Or post the `web.xml`?

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: to my surprise, the jsp page is loaded when I removed the below code:ApplicationContext productContext = RequestContextUtils
    .getWebApplicationContext(request); 

  ProductService productService = (ProductService) productContext
    .getBean("productService");
  List<Product> products = productService.getSelectedProducts(storeId);  so it means jquery is able to load this jsp file. But just that for this 'request' initiated by jquery spring is not able to serve the application context.

Comment: web.xml: has  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>electron</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> . if products.jsp doesn't contain the application context ref.,I'm able to load this jsp file from jquery "$("#products-column").load("jsp/products.jsp?"+"store_id="+response);"

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.
The problem was with the request object that was sent as parameter for the method `RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext`. 
It was:

```
ApplicationContext productContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);
```

I found that request object from jquery doesn't contain attribute `DispatcherServlet.WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE` which is needed to get the bean. But I found alternative method to construct the application context:

```
ApplicationContext productContext = RequestContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(request,servletContext);
```

Here, the servlet context is been passed along with the request.
Servlet context could be obtained as below:

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)
request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

Hence modifying the jsp code to used servlet context explicitly worked for me.